# How the discount renders to totals on checkout section in magento?

Tags: magento

How the discount renders to totals on checkout section in magento?

The subtotal, grandtotal are renders using the template files in designs/.../tax/checkout/ folder..

But, I didn't find the template for discounts which renders on checkout page in magento.

[image: How Discount renders on magento checkout page?]

Answer (score 7):

I got the solution. It is in designs/.../checkout/total/default.phtml file. For discount, By default it will take default.phtml file as define in Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Totals class

Thanks,

Prasanth P

skype: prasanth.p88